# How to get "last saved by" Office file attribute in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, xslf

I am trying to get the "last saved by" attribute from MS Office 2013 file(docx, xlsx, pptx ...). I am using Apache POI, but I can get only the Author of the file with the following code:

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(file);
POIXMLProperties props = new POIXMLProperties(pkg);
props.getCoreProperties().getCreator();
```

Is there a way to get "last saved by" attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookin at the [Apache POI OOXML Properties Extractor](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/POIXMLPropertiesTextExtractor.java) as a good source of inspiration for this sort of problem, we see what you need to do is

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(file);
POIXMLProperties props = new POIXMLProperties(pkg);
PackagePropertiesPart ppropsPart = props.getCoreProperties().getUnderlyingProperties();

Date created = ppropsPart.getCreatedProperty().getValue();
Date modified = ppropsPart.getModifiedProperty().getValue();

String lastModifiedBy = ppropsPart.getLastModifiedByProperty().getValue();
```

That'll give you who last modified the file, when, and when it was created

Answer (score 0):

This should work (not tested) :

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(file);
pkg.getPackageProperties().getLastModifiedByProperty();
```

See : [POI API docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/poi/POIXMLProperties.html)