# Need content-created date of a file in Java

Tags: java, excel, properties, ms-office, metadata

I know there are several questions asked around this, but no Java solution. My question is same:

My goal is to display the date of an Excel file. But if I download the file from the internet, automatically the creation date and modify date are set to current time and date. I looked upon the file's properties, and found that in section 'Details' , under personal information , there is a section called 'Source' and there , it has a property called 'Content Created' with the original date file.

So, I don't want :-
[image: Not this]

but this :-

[image]

Comment: Should be this, isn't it ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225499/how-to-get-last-saved-by-office-file-attribute-in-java

Comment: No, difference is it works for xlsx but not xls

Comment: If I remember correctly POI supports both versions oft the Excel file format

Comment: Yes, but am looking for someway to get content-created which am not able to get via POI

Comment: If you could provide some sample code, it will be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POI does support the `xls` format, though the method for extracting the properties is different from `xlsx`.

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = (HSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new File("sample.xls"));             
SummaryInformation props = wb.getSummaryInformation();
System.out.println("Content Created: " + props.getCreateDateTime());
```

Output:

```
Content Created: Tue Nov 22 07:49:38 PST 2005
```

Here's a screenshot of the `sample.xls` properties that confirms that the required date is being extracted.

[image]

Comment: Thanx, you are a savior, I am completely new to POI.